# How do i highlight all duplicates in 2 columns of a table? (Vba, excel)

Tags: vba, excel

i'm learning vba.

I'm trying to write code which will compare each cell in col 3 to each proceeding cell in the same column, compare each cell in col 5 to each proceeding cell in the same column; and highlight any comparison cell if it, and the cell in the other column of the same row both match the cells they are being compared to in their respective columns.

Code:

```
Sub comparisonDuplicateHighlight()

Set rng = Rows

Dim activeRow As Integer
    activeRow = 2
Dim activeCell1 As Cells
    activeCell1 = Cells(activeRow, 3)
Dim activeCell2 As Cells
    acriveCell2 = Cells(activeRow, 5)
Dim comparisonRow As Integer
    comparisonRow = activeRow + 1
Dim comparisonCell1 As Cells
    comparisonCell1 = Cells(comparisonRow, 3)
Dim comparisonCell2 As Cells
    comparisonCell2 = Cells(comparisonRow, 5)

    For rng = 2 To 25

    If comparisonCell1.Value = activeCell1.Value And comparisonCell2.Value = activeCell2.Value Then
        comparisonCell1.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
        comparisonCell2.Interior.ColorIndex = 6

    Else
        comparisonRow1 = comparisonRow1 + 1
        comparisonRow2 = comparisonRow2 + 1

    End If

End Sub
```

Sheet:[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ywb45.png)

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add this: Can anyone tell me what is wrong with this code? No matter how much i try to improve it, i can't make it run properly.

Comment: `For rng = 2 To 25` what is this line doing in your code?

Comment: It's so that it doesn't keep comparing ad infinity

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot do this with conditional formatting based on a [COUNTIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-53C4DC8E-0E5B-4E32-93DF-9CA5E7DA89ED)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding your last question/comment:

Declare `activeCell1` as a variable type `Range`.

```
Dim activeCell1 As Range
```

Then `Set` the [Range object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx) like,

```
Set activeCell1 = Cells(activeRow, 3)
```

With the range var properly set you can access the [Range.Value property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195193.aspx). Repeat this for all of the range type vars then you can use them like,

```
If comparisonCell1.Value = activeCell1.Value And comparisonCell2.Value = activeCell2.Value Then
```

Comment: It still doesn't work. Ive been staring at this for hours now...am i missing something?
   
    Dim activeRow As Integer
        activeRow = 2
    Dim activeCell1 As Range
        Set activeCell1 = Cells(activeRow, 3)
    Dim activeCell2 As Range
        Set activeCell2 = Cells(activeRow, 5)
    Dim comparisonRow As Integer
        Set comparisonRow = activeRow + 1
    Dim comparisonCell1 As Range
        Set comparisonCell1 = Cells(comparisonRow, 3)
    Dim comparisonCell2 As Range
        Set comparisonCell2 = Cells(comparisonRow, 5)
        For activeRow = 2 To 24

Comment: You **assign** the row numbers (Integers) like `comparisonRow = activeRow + 1` but you `Set` the [Range objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx) like `Set comparisonCell1 = Cells(comparisonRow, 3)`. Two very different things.